# Autorotation being broken by a HERE map subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autorotate

I’m having a trouble with autorotation disappearance on iOS 10, Xcode 8.3.3. I have 2 view controllers inside of another container view controller. The 1st one is an empty view for test. The 2nd one is a map view brought from a 3rd party lib - [HERE Map Starter](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-starter/topics/overview.html), it is installed as an UIView subclass. 
When I:

1. open the app on view1, change orientation of the device - the autorotation happens
2. switch to view 2 (map), autorotation works here too.
3. switch back to view 1, change orientation of the device - the autorotation not happening. // 4. switch to view 2, autorotation works here again.

So I’ll file an issue to the map provider, but the question is: what a UIView can do to stop containing UIViewController to autorotate? Probably I can do the opposite on view 2 disappearance?

Note: 1. shouldAutorotate returns yes and supportedInterfaceOrientations returns UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll in all 3 ViewControllers. 2. VCs are switched programmatically so, that disappearing VC is unloaded.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/andrey-manov/HelloHereMapSwitching) except the 3rd party lib classes, cause I'm not sure about licensing and also it requires registration to work. Instead of the lib there is an empty NMAMapView class - in real solution this is coming from lib.

Comment: Can you submit your code?

Comment: The source code is here https://github.com/andrey-manov/HelloHereMapSwitching except the 3rd party lib classes, cause I'm not sure about licensing. Instead of the lib there is an empty NMAMapView class - in real solution this is coming from lib.

Comment: did you test it on simulator or device ?

Comment: Tested this on devices: iPad, iPhone